# Simple mobile jQuery dropdown menu not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

My issue is, that when the bar is pressed on my phone, it does nothing. When clicked on PC at the same resolution, it works without an issue. I'm not sure what to do, I haven't seen a fix anywhere else.

Here is the site that it is used on so you can see the issue first hand: http://www.briansamu.com

```
// This the jQuery

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".burger-nav").on("click", function() {

        $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open");
        // The open class sets the height of the UL to: height: auto;

    });
});
```

Thank you advance.

Comment: Works for me on mac and android. Are you using an iphone by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Click functions for phones are different from that of browsers. To fix these issues use [Hammer Js](https://hammerjs.github.io) which help in handling all click for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Is this issue is with iphone or ipad?
if this is the case try button instead of `<a>` tag